# Determining wether a set is open or not in given topology or $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

For each $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $a^2+b^2\neq 0$, Let $$E(a,b,c)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ax+by+c=0\}$$
and let $\tau$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by the class $\{E(a,b,c): a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^3,a^2+b^2\neq 0\}$. Examine wether the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,x^2+y^2 < 1\}$ is an open set in the topological space $(\mathbb{R^2},\tau)$

I think yes. It should be discrete space as each singleton set $\{ (a,b)\}=E(1,0,-p) \cap E(0,1,-q)$ is open. Its discrete space.
So every set is open?
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. The set of  sets $E(a,b,c)$ is just the set of all lines, and any single point is  the intersection of two lines, and thus the space is discreet. It is more interesting if you take the topology generated by the complements of the $E(a,b,c).$

Comment: Are you sure the $E(a,b)$ weren’t supposed to be the closed sets instead? Otherwise, yes.